# get full sized profile picture with facebook connect

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im using facebook connect to register users and this line is used to get their profile picture:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $session['uid'] .'/picture?type=large';
```

But the picture being returned is only 200 pixels wide. Is it possible to get the full sized profile picture from facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No for a profile picture there isn't. The 'large' size is the largest one returned by the API.

You could try requesting the user's cover photo. That will be much larger and you'll get a json array instead of a redirect to a photo.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME_OR_ID?fields=cover
```